# How to auto-adjust GridView item appearance and width depending on window width

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, windows-10, uwp-xaml

I'm trying to get my `GridView` to automatically adjust the appearance of its items depending on screen width but every time I snap my app's window, the `GridView` items keep getting bunched too close together. How can I ensure that each `GridView` item will appear on its own line and highlight the entire row like a `ListView` item when hovered over when the window is snapped to 1 side or less than a certain width (say 720 - which is often used for the MasterDetailsView - **CompactModeThresholdWidth="720"**)?

*Wide window*

[image]

*Snapped window*

[image]

*Snapped window (expected result)*

[image]

*MainPage.xaml*

```
<Page
    x:Class="MyApp.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:data="using:MyApp.Models"
    mc:Ignorable="d">

    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <StackPanel Margin="0,0,0,20" Grid.Row="0">
            <TextBlock Text="Hello World"/>
        </StackPanel>

        <GridView Grid.Row="1" 
                  IsItemClickEnabled="True"
                  ItemsSource="{x:Bind GridItems}" 
                  ItemClick="GridView_ItemClick">
            <GridView.ItemContainerStyle>
                <Style TargetType="GridViewItem">
                    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Left"/>
                </Style>
            </GridView.ItemContainerStyle>
            <GridView.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <data:MyGridViewPanel/>
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </GridView.ItemsPanel>
            <GridView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate x:DataType="data:GridItemMain">
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <TextBlock Grid.Column="0"
                                   Text="{Binding Icon}" 
                                   Style="{StaticResource TitleTextBlockStyle}" 
                                   FontFamily="Segoe MDL2 Assets"/>
                        <TextBlock Grid.Column="1"
                                   Text="{Binding Title}" 
                                   Style="{StaticResource TitleTextBlockStyle}"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </GridView.ItemTemplate>
        </GridView>
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

*MainPage.xaml.cs*

```
    public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
    {
        public List<GridItemMain> GridItems;

        public MainPage()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();

            GridItems = GridItemManager.GetGridItems();
        }
    }
```

*MainGridItem.cs*

```
    public class MainGridItem
    {
        public string Icon { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
    }

    public class GridItemManager
    {
        public static List<MainGridItem> GetGridItems()
        {
            var gridItems = new List<MainGridItem>();

            gridItems.Add(new MainGridItem { Icon = "\uE770", Title = "System" });
            gridItems.Add(new MainGridItem { Icon = "\uE772", Title = "Devices" });
            gridItems.Add(new MainGridItem { Icon = "\uEC75", Title = "Phone" });
            gridItems.Add(new MainGridItem { Icon = "\uE774", Title = "Network & Internet" });
            gridItems.Add(new MainGridItem { Icon = "\uE771", Title = "Personalisation" });

            return gridItems;
        }
    }
```

**MyGridViewPanel.cs**

```
public class MyGridViewPanel : Panel
{
    private double _maxWidth;
    private double _maxHeight;
    protected override Size ArrangeOverride(Size finalSize)
    {
        var x = 0.0;
        var y = 0.0;
        double width = Window.Current.Bounds.Width;
        if (width <= 720)
        {
            foreach (var child in Children)
            {  
               
                var newpos = new Rect(0, y, width, _maxHeight);
                child.Arrange(newpos);
                y += _maxHeight;
            }
            return finalSize;
        }
        else {
            foreach (var child in Children)
            {
                if ((_maxWidth + x) > finalSize.Width)
                {
                    x = 0;
                    y += _maxHeight;
                }
                var newpos = new Rect(x, y, _maxWidth, _maxHeight);
                child.Arrange(newpos);
                x += _maxWidth;
            }
            return finalSize;
        }
            
    }
    protected override Size MeasureOverride(Size availableSize)
    {
        double width = Window.Current.Bounds.Width;
        if (width <= 720)
        {
            foreach (var child in Children)
            {
                child.Measure(new Size(width, availableSize.Height));
                var desiredheight = child.DesiredSize.Height;
                if (desiredheight > _maxHeight)
                    _maxHeight = desiredheight;
            }
            return new Size(width, _maxHeight * Children.Count);
        }
        else {
            foreach (var child in Children)
            {
                child.Measure(availableSize);
                var desirtedwidth = child.DesiredSize.Width;
                if (desirtedwidth > _maxWidth)
                    _maxWidth = desirtedwidth;
                var desiredheight = child.DesiredSize.Height;
                if (desiredheight > _maxHeight)
                    _maxHeight = desiredheight;
            }
            var itemperrow = Math.Floor(availableSize.Width / _maxWidth);
            var rows = Math.Ceiling(Children.Count / itemperrow);
            return new Size(itemperrow * _maxWidth, _maxHeight * rows);
        }
        
    }
}
```

*Update*

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to display an item on each line when the window is less than 720px, you could get the current window's width in the ArrangeOverride and MeasureOverride method, then resize the item and re-layout each item to show them in each row. For example:

MyGridViewPanel.cs

```
public class MyGridViewPanel : Panel
{
    private double _maxWidth;
    private double _maxHeight;
    protected override Size ArrangeOverride(Size finalSize)
    {
        var x = 0.0;
        var y = 0.0;
        double width = Window.Current.Bounds.Width;
        if (width <= 720)
        {
            foreach (var child in Children)
            {  
               
                var newpos = new Rect(0, y, width, _maxHeight);
                child.Arrange(newpos);
                y += _maxHeight;
            }
            return finalSize;
        }
        else {
            foreach (var child in Children)
            {
                if ((_maxWidth + x) > finalSize.Width)
                {
                    x = 0;
                    y += _maxHeight;
                }
                var newpos = new Rect(x, y, _maxWidth, _maxHeight);
                child.Arrange(newpos);
                x += _maxWidth;
            }
            return finalSize;
        }
            
    }
    protected override Size MeasureOverride(Size availableSize)
    {
        double width = Window.Current.Bounds.Width;
        if (width <= 720)
        {
            foreach (var child in Children)
            {
                child.Measure(new Size(width, availableSize.Height));
                var desiredheight = child.DesiredSize.Height;
                if (desiredheight > _maxHeight)
                    _maxHeight = desiredheight;
            }
            return new Size(width, _maxHeight * Children.Count);
        }
        else {
            foreach (var child in Children)
            {
                child.Measure(availableSize);
                var desirtedwidth = child.DesiredSize.Width;
                if (desirtedwidth > _maxWidth)
                    _maxWidth = desirtedwidth;
                var desiredheight = child.DesiredSize.Height;
                if (desiredheight > _maxHeight)
                    _maxHeight = desiredheight;
            }
            var itemperrow = Math.Floor(availableSize.Width / _maxWidth);
            var rows = Math.Ceiling(Children.Count / itemperrow);
            return new Size(itemperrow * _maxWidth, _maxHeight * rows);
        }
        
    }
}
```

Comment: Your suggestion did work but currently, the right-hand side of the highlight border is not visible. Is there a way to highlight the whole row background (like in my '_Snapped window (expected result)_' screenshot)?

Comment: Do you mean when you hovered over the item, you want to highlight the whole row background like ListView? If it is, you can change the default style of ItemContainerStyle and find the "PointerOver" Visual State, then add `<Setter Target="Root.RevealBackground" Value="{ThemeResource ListViewItemRevealBackgroundPointerOver}"/>` in it.

Comment: What about the right-hand side of the highlight border not visible issue? How Can I fix this so that it is visible?

Comment: Got it, but when I shrink the width of the window to less than 720px, the highlight border worked well, the right-hand side is also visible. I can't reproduce this issue. Can you describe the detailed steps about how this issue occur?

Comment: Hello again. I really do not know what has gone wrong with my project. You can find my latest code here [MacaronLover's Github](https://github.com/macaronlover/MD)

Comment: Hi, the code you provided from github does not seem to be related to the code snippet above, you used MasterDetailsView instead of GridView and where did you use the MyGridViewPanel?

Comment: Hi. Apologies, wrong code. My code is exactly the same as the one in your answer. If you create a sample project, that should help me compare code but if I still cannot get this to work, then I will consider changing the default style of `ItemContainerStyle`.

Comment: Here is my simple [sample](https://github.com/wcj233/GridViewApp), you can check it.

Comment: How can I get the text to wrap if it all cannot fit on 1 line?

Comment: You can set the Width and TextWrapping for TextBlock, once the actual width of content  is greater than the Width, it will wrap.

Comment: Setting the width does not sound like a good idea due to the different screen sizes

Comment: If you do not define any sort of width restriction, your TextBox can expand infinitely in width, it will not wrap its text.

Comment: Can this be set in C# within the if statement? I only want to set the width when the window width is or less than 720.

Comment: You can try to use Grid to replace StackPanel in your DataTemplate and divide into two columns to place your TextBlocks. For example: `<DataTemplate><Grid><Grid.ColumnDefinitions><ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/><ColumnDefinition Width="*"/></Grid.ColumnDefinitions>......</Grid></DataTemplate>`